# Smalltalk - Seaside Reporting

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

I'm adding my transactions to a dictionary, using a UUID as the key and the transaction object as the value - this is what I call my `ledger`:

Example (entriesForPosting is a `Set` of `Array`s, each containing a credit entry and a debit entry):

```
   postToGL
    entriesForPosting do: [ :ea | GeneralLedger ledger at: (ea at: 1) mUID put: (ea at: 1).  "credit"
                                  GeneralLedger ledger at:(ea at: 2) mUID put: (ea at: 2) ].  "debit"
```

We then report this ledger like this:

```
renderReport
    GLReport := WATableReport new
        rows: GeneralLedger getGLPostings asOrderedCollection ;
        columns: (OrderedCollection new
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: each  ]
                title: 'ID');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mDate ]
                title: 'Transaction Date');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mAmount ]
                title: 'Amount');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: ((GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mGLAC mAccountCode)]
                title: 'GLAC');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: ((GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mFund mFundCode)]
                title: 'Fund');
            yourself);
        rowColors: #(lightblue lightyellow);
        rowPeriod: 1;
        yourself.
```

The problem I'm having is, this report isn't ordered. I.e., the transactions display out of order - and I don't see any rhyme or reason to why they're reported how they are:

For example,

```
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 100 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 110 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 120 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 130 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 140 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 150 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 160 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 170 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 180 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 190 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr buildTransactionFor: 200 against: someGLAC.
spndMgr postTransactions.
```

Gives me the following:
[image]

---

I've tried the following:

```
renderReport
    |columnToSortBy|

    GLReport := WATableReport new
        rows: GeneralLedger getGLPostings asOrderedCollection ;
        columns: (OrderedCollection new
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each)  mIdentity ]
                title: 'Identity');
            add: (columnToSortBy := (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mDate ]
                title: 'Transaction Date') );               
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mAmount ]
                title: 'Amount');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: ((GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mGLAC mAccountCode)]
                title: 'GLAC');
            add: (WAReportColumn
                renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: ((GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mFund mFundCode)]
                title: 'Fund');
            yourself);
        rowColors: #(lightblue lightyellow);
        rowPeriod: 1;
        sortColumn: columnToSortBy;
        yourself.
```

But this throws an error on rendering:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `WAReportColumn` understands `#sortBlock:`. This block is initialized to `[ :a :b | a <= b ]` where a and b would be some `glPosting` objects I assume. If this sort behavior doesn't suit you, simply pass a different sort block to the column.
2. `WAReportTable` understands `#sortColumn:`. Pass the column you want to have sorted by default like so:

   ```
   ...
   add: (columnToSortBy := (WAReportColumn
       renderBlock: [ :each :html | html emphasis: (GeneralLedger getTransactionByID: each) mAmount ]
       title: 'Amount';
       yourself));
   ...
   rowColors: #(lightblue lightyellow);
   rowPeriod: 1;
   sortColumn: columnToSortBy;
   yourself.
   ```

Comment: You discovered a pretty ugly bug. The block you pass into `#renderBlock:title:` takes two arguments (as you correctly gathered from the examples). But `WAReportColumn` will call that block with **only one** argument. There's no quick solution here. My advice is to introduce a new instance variable called `renderBlock` and to use a distinct `valueBlock`. You could initialize the `valueBlock` to `[ :row | row ]` and the `renderBlock` to `[ :row :html | html render: (self valueForRow: row) asString ]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there somewhere to report this?

Comment: You're welcome. The place for discussion and support is the Seaside mailing list (http://www.seaside.st/community/mailinglist).

Answer (score 1):

If you add something like the following to your ledger,

```
GeneralLedger>>columnDescriptions
    ^#('Transaction Date' #(mDate)
       'Amount' #(mAmount)
       'GLAC' #(mGlac mAccountCode)
       'Fund' #(mFund mFundCode))
```

you can build up your report columns like this

```
ledger columnDescriptions pairsDo: [ :title :accessorCollection | |column|
    column := WAReportColumn new
        title: title;
        renderBlock: [:each :html | |temp|
            temp := GeneralLedger getTransactionById: each.
            accessorCollection do: [ :accessor |
                temp := temp perform: accessor ].
            html emphasis: temp];
        yourself.
    report columns add: column].
```

If you need different kinds of reports, it makes sense to start using Magritte
(or Deltawerken). There you define the fields with separate objects, and just tell
the report which fields to render.